# .dockerignore not being read on image build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been stuck on this for awhile. I would like docker to ignore a particular directory when building an image, because my user account does not have permissions to read that directory. I cannot move it, so that's not an alternative.

This is the structure of my project. `docker/data` is the directory that I do not have permissions to read, and `docker/node-express.dockerfile` is the image I'm trying to build.

[image]

Running `docker build --no-cache --tag node-express --file ./docker/node-express.dockerfile .` in the root directory outputs the error

```
error checking context: 'can't stat '/home/anthony/Repositories/Anthony-Monterrosa/aws-postgres-node-stack/docker/data''.
```

After this error and a bit of googling I learned about `.dockerignore` files, and made one in the root directory. The following is the file's text.

```
docker/data
```

I ran the command again but got an identical error. A bit more googling and I found out about [image-specific](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12886#issuecomment-480575928) `.dockerignore` files, so I set `DOCKER_BUILDKIT` to `1`, created `docker/node-express.dockerfile.dockerignore` with the following content

```
data
docker/data
```

(I am not sure how relative paths work with image-specific .dockerignores, so I added both). Ran the command again, but still with the same error.

So, I don't seem to have ignores working correctly with either `.dockerignore` file, or both. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you try moving your `.dockerignore` file to your docker/data/ directory?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal no, because I don't have read permissions. So I can't even open the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is:

> error checking context: 'can't stat '/home/anthony/Repositories/Anthony-Monterrosa/aws-postgres-node-stack/docker/data''.

So looks there is some operation before `.dockerignore` effect.

As there is no context content in your `docker` folder, I suggest you just add `docker` in `.dockerignore`.

This way, although still error, but the build will continue like next:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/trial2020/trial$ docker build -t abcd:1 -f docker/Dockerfile .
ERRO[0000] Tar: Can't stat file /home/shubuntu1/trial2020/trial to tar: open 
/home/shubuntu1/trial2020/trial/docker/data: permission denied
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/1 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
 ---> 3556258649b2
Successfully built 3556258649b2
Successfully tagged abcd:1
```

**UPDATE why according to your comments:**

You may want to have a look for docker-ce source code, [build.go](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/cli/cli/command/image/build.go#L299) & [context.go](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/cli/cli/command/image/build/context.go#L36):

**build.go**:

```
if err := build.ValidateContextDirectory(contextDir, excludes); err != nil {
    return errors.Errorf("error checking context: '%s'.", err)
}
```

**context.go**:

```
func ValidateContextDirectory(srcPath string, excludes []string) error {
    contextRoot, err := getContextRoot(srcPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    pm, err := fileutils.NewPatternMatcher(excludes)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return filepath.Walk(contextRoot, func(filePath string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            if os.IsPermission(err) {
                return errors.Errorf("can't stat '%s'", filePath)
            }
            if os.IsNotExist(err) {
                return errors.Errorf("file ('%s') not found or excluded by .dockerignore", filePath)
            }
            return err
        }

        // skip this directory/file if it's not in the path, it won't get added to the context
        if relFilePath, err := filepath.Rel(contextRoot, filePath); err != nil {
            return err
        } else if skip, err := filepathMatches(pm, relFilePath); err != nil {
            return err
        } else if skip {
            if f.IsDir() {
                return filepath.SkipDir
            }
            return nil
        }
......
    })
}
```

Before docker daemon tar the build context, it will first try to validate the context directory:

1. `docker/data` in `.dockerignore`:

   It will use `Walk` to ergodic all things under `docker`, when it comes to `docker/data`, next code finally make the build exit, so you did not get image generated:

   ```
    if os.IsPermission(err) {
        return errors.Errorf("can't stat '%s'", filePath)
    }
   ```
2. `docker` in `.dockerignore`:

   Same as above, difference is next code will effect when comes to the match `docker` in `.dockerignore`:

   ```
    return filepath.SkipDir
   ```

   This will make the `Walk` ignore the subfolders of `docker`, then `docker/data` no chance to be ergodic, so no permission error there.

   The `ERRO[0000] Tar: Can't stat file` comes from other later steps which won't exit the image build.

Comment: Update the reason.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.